# How do I pass parameters/argument to a callback function?

Tags: java, android

A naive question as I am a bit new to programming.
I am Working on an Android application where I need to pass parameters to the callback method(Not sure if the verbiage is right).

I want the parameters/variables to be available to the Main Function. I am calling the Caller to invoke my main function and hence need the parameters to pass from the Caller.

something like the classic functions does

**Example**

```
method(param1, param2);

function method(param1, param2){
    Log(param1 + param 2);
      ....
}
```

I need the below code to achieve the functionality as the above example

the code is as follows:

```
//Caller:- 
 getChioceList(new MyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(ArrayList<String> value) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Config CallBack " + value);
                }
});

//Interface
public interface MyCallback{
    void onCallback(ArrayList<String> value);
}
```

//Main function : I want some parameters to be passed to this method

```
 public void getChioceList(final MyCallback myCallback) {
     final ArrayList < String > result = new ArrayList < > ();
     final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
     Query query = ref.child("Device").orderByChild("home").equalTo(homeID);
     query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshots: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 result.add(dataSnapshots.getKey());
                 Log.i(TAG, "Config: get Input 3 " + result);
             }
             myCallback.onCallback(result);
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
     });
 }
```

Please help...

Comment: Do you want to pass some param to`getChioceList` this method?

Comment: I didn't get your question. You can add your parameters to the interface or the main function.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Yes, I want to pass the parameters to the maim function getChioceList  as I want to pass the value of homeID to the method when it is called.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Sorry tone unclear. I want the params to be passed to the main function "getChoiceList()"  when it is called. The main function "getChoiceList()" has a variable "homeID" the value of which I need to pass to the main function, so I can use it to build the query.

Comment: Can't you change `getChoiceList`'s signature to `getChioceList(final MyCallback myCallback, int homeID)` ?!

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar I did. The next step will be to call the method. How to call this with the params? this is the caller "getChioceList(new MyCallback(){...}" as in the code above. Where do I introduce the params?

Comment: add a comma after the callback and write your parameter. For example,  `getChioceList(new MyCallback(){...},  1234);`

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Thanks. That worked exactly the way I wanted. :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. But I suggest you take a java/kotlin course before you start developing android applications and struggle with more complicated concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i understand. Basically you want to pass something to a callback method.

I would suggest to create another class that will implement `ValueEventListener`.

Like so

```
public class SomeClassThatWillImplement implements ValueEventListener {

    private String cVar1;
    private String cVar2;

    public SomeClassThatWillImplement (String param1, String parma2) {
        this.cVar1 = param1;
        this.cVar2 = param2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        //Do something with this.cVar1
        //Do something with this.cVar2
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            result.add(dataSnapshots.getKey());
             Log.i(TAG, "Config: get Input 3 " + result);
        }
        myCallback.onCallback(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Do something with this.cVar1
        //Do something with this.cVar2
    }

}
```

To use above class,

```
public void getChioceList(final MyCallback myCallback) {
    final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = ref.child("Device").orderByChild("home").equalTo(homeID);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new SomeClassThatWillImplement(param1, param2));
}
```

Hopefully this helps